# Qt Android bluetooth socket write issues on Android 5.1.1 and 6.0

Tags: android, c++, qt, bluetooth

I'm developing an app with Qt for Android, it uses bluetooth. Target API in Qt creator is set to 16 (4.1 as far as I remember). Up to 5.0 there are no issues with app but since 5.1.1 there is an issue with write to rfcom bluetooth socket. Here  is what I've managed to get out of the logs.

Just before QBluetoothSocket::connected signal received I can see:

```
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
W/bt-btif ( 4541): new conn_srvc id:26, app_id:1
W/bt-btif ( 4541): bta_dm_pm_ssr conn_srvc id:26, app_id:1
W/bt-btif ( 4541): bta_dm_pm_ssr:2, lat:1200
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
E/BluetoothRemoteDevices( 4541): setRfcommConnected true
D/BluetoothSocket(21782): getInputStream(): myUserId = 0
D/BluetoothSocket(21782): getOutputStream(): myUserId = 0
```

Seems like socket is connected, but I wonder what are all those `BT_WAKE is asserted already` and should I consider them first symptom of "something went wrong", however I succesfully get "connected" signal from socket and start using socket. I'm sending 5 bytes of data right after socket is connected.

```
D/IOP_DB_BT( 4541): db_query: id DisableSniff :: key KEY_BDADDR, value 00:06:66:64:fd:4a
D/IOP_DB_BT( 4541): db_query: result 1
D/IOP_DB_BT( 4541): db_query: id ExtendSniffTime :: key KEY_BDADDR, value 00:06:66:64:fd:4a
D/IOP_DB_BT( 4541): db_query: result 1
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_upio ( 4541): ..proc_btwrite_timeout..
```

This is what I can see in logs right after write.

Than in my data send timeout slot (5 sec timeout). I'm trying to read whatever is inside the buffer and get

```
W/bt-btif ( 4541): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 4541): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 4541): proc dm_pm_timer expires
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): proc btwrite assertion
E/bt-btif ( 4541): bta_dm_pm_btm_status  hci_status=36
```

And when closing timed out socket I get

```
D/BluetoothSocket(21782): close() in, this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@21e99957, channel: 1, state: CONNECTED
D/BluetoothSocket(21782): close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@21e99957, channel: 1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@d78fc44, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@39f8512dmSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@d447662 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@340473f3 fd:FileDescriptor[52]
D/BluetoothSocket(21782): Closing mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@d447662 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@340473f3 fd:FileDescriptor[52]
W/System.err(21782): java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
W/System.err(21782):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:651)
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
W/System.err(21782):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
W/System.err(21782):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
W/System.err(21782):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bluetooth.QtBluetoothInputStreamThread.run(QtBluetoothInputStreamThread.java:77)
W/bt-btif ( 4541): bta_jv_rfc_port_to_cb(port_handle:0xc):jv handle:0x0 not FOUND
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): BT_WAKE is asserted already
E/bt-btm  ( 4541): Reset sec_bd_name and name flag. (BR/EDR link)
E/bt-btm  ( 4541): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
W/bt-btif ( 4541): bta_dm_acl_change(), event : 1
W/bt-btif ( 4541): bta_dm_acl_change(), event : 2
E/BluetoothRemoteDevices( 4541): aclStateChangeCallback:  State:DisConnected to Device:00:06:66:64:FD:XX
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1352): Received android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
D/BluetoothUtils( 4541): getBtEnabledContainers(): btContainers = []
D/KnoxKeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1015): BroadcastReceiver onReceive
D/KnoxKeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1015): BroadcastReceiver onReceive action: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
D/KnoxKeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1015): BroadcastReceiver ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
I/TrustAgent.Tracker( 2416): [BluetoothConnectionTracker] Bluetooth disconnect broadast for DeviceName 00:06:66:64:FD:4A
V/BroadcastQueue( 1015): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{11c4d283 u0 android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{3da73a96 4541:com.android.bluetooth/1002}
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1352): isGear1: device is not B1!
D/ActivityManager( 1015): startService callerProcessName:com.sec.android.automotive.drivelink, calleePkgName: com.sec.android.automotive.drivelink
V/[CarModeFW](21435): BTEventsHandlerService-onHandleIntent: Action = android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED State = -2147483648 Previous = -2147483648
D/BluetoothAdapterService( 4541): getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@11578ddd
D/BtConfig.SecureMode( 4541): isSecureModeOn:false
D/SecContentProvider( 1015): query(), uri = 4 selection = isProfileAuthorizedBySecurityPolicy
D/[CarModeFW](21435): ConnectivityManager-handleMessage BLUETOOTH_ACL_DISCONNECTED
D/[CarModeFW](21435): ConnectivityManager-handleMessage BLUETOOTH_ACL_DISCONNECTED onNotifyBluetoothDeviceDisconnected
D/ActivityManager( 1015): startService callerProcessName:com.android.bluetooth, calleePkgName: com.android.bluetooth
I/BluetoothPbapService( 4541): action: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED, state: -2147483648
D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1352): onDataActivity: direction=0
D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1352): updateDataIcon, mDataDirectionIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_fully_connected_lte mDataConnected = true
V/BroadcastQueue( 1015): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{11c4d283 u0 android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{eac93e8 7760:com.sec.android.app.shealth:remote/u0a70}
V/BroadcastQueue( 1015): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{11c4d283 u0 android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{34817d39 1995:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search/u0a62}
I/BTConnectionReceiver( 1995): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, [BluetoothDevice: address=00:06:66:64:FD:4A, alias=null, name=BeSteadyOne010347, majorDeviceClass=7936, deviceClass=7936]
I/BluetoothClassifier( 1995): Bluetooth Device Name: BeSteadyOne010347
V/BroadcastQueue( 1015): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{11c4d283 u0 android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{1ab7ce01 22089:com.skype.raider/u0a300}
W/[CarMode](21435): [BluetoothConnectivityListener]-Device BeSteadyOne010347 not registered as Car (Not found in Settings)
D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1352): refreshViews connected={ data } level=1 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020598/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_1_auto_rotate mobileLabel=Plus wifiLabel= emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel=Plus mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020598/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_1_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0201ac/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_1 mDataDirectionIconId=0x7f020494/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_fully_connected_lte mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020598/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_1_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f02047a/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_lte mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f0201b2/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4g mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x0/(null) mQSWifiIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f02064b/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f02065e/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
D/STATUSBAR-WifiTile( 1352): onWifiSignalChanged enabled=false enabledDesc:null
E/Watchdog( 1015): !@Sync 711 [12-14 16:06:15.605]
D/bt_vendor( 4541): op for 7
D/bt_upio ( 4541): ..proc_btwrite_timeout..
```

I have no more clue why this does not work and what else can I try to make it work. Maybe I'm missing some new permissions to make Bluetooth work.

Permissions I have in my manifest (permissions generated by Qt)

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: I'v got almost same problem with Androids from 5.0 to 7.0. But in my case it's disconnecting periodicaly. I'v noticed when charger plugged in - everything works great. Seems like kinda powersaving in Android. On Android 8.0 and 9.0 everything works great without any disconnects.
My Qt version is 5.13 but I guess it's Android version issue

Comment: I've noticed that, depending on the Service BT implementation, if Android doesn't ack back on every single message, the connection gets destroyed.